# Canonical link seo friendly

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo, canonical-link

I have a link structure that is managed by an apache server. Some pages can be called with different url but with a php redirect the user will see just the canonical url for the page.

**canonical url:** www.example.it/490/persons/jan-antone-vian

**generic url that call the same page:** www.example.it/490/

My question is if it is correct to insert the url with just the id (www.example.it/490/) in some links (is much easier to manage the links) for SEO?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, it's sure  that a well constructed URL is better for SEO (url with keywords)

What you can do, and what you seems to have done :

- keep the www.example.it/490/ URL for sharing,
- add a 301 redirection to your
  www.example.it/490/persons/jan-antone-vian when arriving in the first
  url (www.example.it/490/). The SEO juice should be transfered to the
  full url constructed.

Google says that ONE (and only one) URL has to be related to ONE (and only one) content, so you cannot let the both url displaying the same content. (you could be penalised for duplicate content...)

Note that a 301 is announced that it transfers the FULL SEO JUICE, **but** it's common to not do many 301 redirections in cascade.